# Document views reporting

Tags: document, view, access, reports

Is there a way to get data or reporting around how often a document is accessed on SharePoint?  How can I create a report that would allow me to determine how often a document was viewed or opened?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by configuring **audit settings** for a site collection

**To configure audit settings do the following**

- Go to root site.
- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site collection audit settings .

[image]

- In `Documents and Items` Section.
- Select `Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties`

[image]

**To open Audit Report**

- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > `Audit log reports`.
- Seleect Content viweing.

[image]

**Note:**

`Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties` is not available for SharePoint Online sites.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  What if I dont have the "opening or downloading documents" checkbox available on my settings option?  (See screen shot that I added above in my original inquiry)

Comment: This option is not available for SharePoint Online sites, it is on  SharePoint on-prem 2013, by the way, you didn't mention your version in question tags :) anyway no problem hope to help other people use SharePoint on-prem

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for not including all the necessary info.  So, does this mean there is no way to track document utilization in SharePoint online?  Any workarounds?

Comment: based on my humble knowledge yes no OOTB audit for opening documents, Meanwhile let me check if there is any workarounds or any apps that handle that and will come back to you soon? also, please if you consider this answer  based on your submitted question please upvote and set as answer :) thanks

Comment: Hey @M.Qassas - was just curious if you might have found some alternative solution pertaining to our discussion yesterday? :)

Comment: I am sorry @ErinA unfortunately it is not available as i told you before and till now not find any OOTB solution :(https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/enabling-opening-or-downloading-documents-viewing/8e338061-ef7c-4c79-9f9c-49f0e5d787a3